# Different email acount on different MX priority

Tags: email, email-server, mx-record, email-bounces

Say you have the ff. email server:

`server1.com` has the mailbox `foo@example.com`

`server2.com` has the mailbox `bar@example.com`

If the MX priority settings are:

```
Priority: 0
Destination: server1.com

Priority: 10
Destination: server2.com
```

Will sending an email to `bar@example.com` eventually arrive at `server2.com` or will it fail immediately because it doesn't exist in `server1.com`?

Comment: Short answer: no. You need your MTA to route their messages to both local and remote MDA. In postfix, that's probably in your `transport_maps`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `server1` is accessible and if it answered so it could be interpreted that `bar@example.com` is permanently undeliverable (error code `5xx`), the sending server should give up and don't try other servers. In this case it drops mail as undeliverable and optionally creates a non-delivery notification to the original sender.

If `server1` answered with error code `4xx` (temporary error) for `bar@example.com`, sending server should try to connect to another recipient server (`server2`) and try to deliver mail to it. If it also throws an error, sending server may queue and retry both servers for some extended period of time (say, a week), and then it gives up and sends non-delivery to original sender. Also it may send intermediate DSN about mail delay.

If `server1` is inaccessible, sending server has no other option than connect to `server2`. The behaviour for `foo@example.com` in this case is the same.